# Proper data structure for a bi-directional key<->val lookup table

Tags: r, data-structures

I have a set of key (character) <-> hash (integer) associations in R. I'd like to store these associations in a single structure that allows me to reference a key/hash pair by key, and also by hash.

So something like

```
"hello" <-> 1234
```

in variable `db`.

And access it with (ish; doesn't have to be this exact access syntax):

```
db["hello"] -> 1234
db[1234] -> "hello"
```

I tried using a data frame, and naming the rownames the keys. But then I cannot reference a row by hash integer. If I use hash integers as rownames, then I cannot reference by keyname, etc.

My current solution is to keep two dbs as two data frames. One has the hashes as rownames, the other has the keys as rownames. This works, but it seems a bit awkward and repetitive to keep around two identical data frames (other than their rownames).

I'd like it to be super fast in both directions :). I think this means O(log(n)) for character direction, and O(1) for integer direction, but I'm not a data-structure/algorithm expert. O(log(n)) in the integer direction is probably OK, but I think O(n) (needs to traverse the whole db solution) in either direction will weigh things down too much.

The db is also bijective. That is, each key maps to exactly one value, and each value maps to exactly one key.

EDIT: Thanks for the posts so far:

Running a few tests, the match technique is definitely slower than a keyed data.table. As Martin pointed out, this is due solely to the time required for match to create the keyed table. That is, both match and a keyed data.table perform a binary search to find the value. But regardless, match is too slow for my needs when returning a single value. So I'll code up a data.table solution and post.

```
> system.time(match(1,x))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.742   0.054   0.792 
> system.time(match(1,x))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.748   0.064   0.806 
> system.time(match(1e7,x))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.747   0.067   0.808 
> system.time(x.table[1])
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> system.time(x.table[1e7])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.001   0.001   0.000 
> system.time(x.table[1e7])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.005   0.000   0.005 
> system.time(x.table[1])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.001   0.000   0.000 
> system.time(x.table[1])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.020   0.001   0.038
```

EDIT2:

I went with the fmatch solution and a named vector. I liked the simplicity of the match approach, but I'm doing repeated lookups on the db, so the performance hit of recreating the hash table on each call to match was too great.

fmatch has the same interface as match, works on the same named vector data type, etc. It just caches/memoizes the created hash table, so that subsequent calls on the named vector only have to perform the hash lookup. All of this is abstracted from the caller, so fmatch is simply a dropin for match.

Simple wrapper code for the bidirectional lookup:

```
getChunkHashes = function(chunks, db) {
        return(db[fmatch(chunks, names(db))])
}

getChunks = function(chunkHashes, db) {
        return(names(db[fmatch(chunkHashes, db)]))
}
```

Comment: Might be good to add a note about any performance constraints you may have (ie does it have to be super fast in both directions...?)

Comment: Perhaps the excellent [fastmatch](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/fastmatch/index.html) package might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given :

> The db is also bijective. That is, each key maps to exactly one value, and each value maps to exactly one key.

Then I'd suggest hash solutions (e.g. the [hash package](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/hash/index.html)), the [fastmatch package](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/fastmatch/index.html), or `data.table::chmatch`. A keyed join in `data.table` is more intended for *ordered* multi-column keys, and/or grouped data, which isn't really the problem you have.

Answer (score 4):

A base approach is to use a named vector:

```
db <- c(hello = 1234, hi = 123, hey = 321)
```

To go from key(s) to value(s), use `[`:

```
db[c("hello", "hey")]
# hello   hey 
#  1234   321
```

To go from value(s) to key(s) is a little trickier:

```
names(db)[match(c(321, 123), db)]
# [1] "hey" "hi"
```

(Note that `match(x, y)` returns the index of the *first* match of `x` in `y`, so this approach only works well if your map is injective, something you did not make clear in your question.)

If you find that last usage a little too "heavy", you can definitely write your own function.

**Note**: as pointed out, this approach is potentially slow in the value-to-key direction, so it may not be ideal for repetitive bi-directional access of a large map. For its defense, it is is easy to implement, does not require any package other than `base`, and will do a very decent job for 99% of people's needs. If nothing, it can be used here as a benchmark against faster alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, and yes this db is injective. My only concern for the match approach is that I think match has to iterate over every item in the db. Worst case the item is the last one, etc. So O(n) in the integer direction. I'm hoping for something O(log(n)) or O(1) in the integer direction.

Comment: What if the db was sorted by val on ascending integer. Is there a flag for match to say that this is the case, so that it can use a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: @claytontstanley I might investigate **data.table** and environments as hash tables.

Answer (score 2):

More of an elaboration on @claytonstanley 's concern about @flodel 's response. `match` makes a hash of one of it's arguments then searches for the other. The cost is in the creation of the hash rather than the lookup

```
> n = 1e7; x = seq_len(n)
> system.time(match(1, x))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.156   0.064   1.222 
> system.time(match(n, x))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.152   0.068   1.221
```

and it's amortized over the number of look-ups performed

```
> y = sample(x)
> system.time(match(y, x))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.112   0.052   2.167
```

so you definitely want the look-up to be 'vectorized'.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. `1e7` is a rather large choice and the response time not that bad. It would be nice to know a little more about @claytontstanley's usage: what `n` will be, how many access-es will be needed, can they all be done at the same time, etc.